# To add and display formatted data as a block of code in Vue.js

Tags: html, antd, nuxtjs3

In order to save a block of code to DB

```
<template>
  <!-- some content -->
  <NuxtErrorBoundary @error="someErrorLogger">
    <!-- You use the default slot to render your content -->
    <template #error="{ error, clearError }">
      You can display the error locally here: {{ error }}
      <button @click="clearError">
        This will clear the error.
      </button>
    </template>
  </NuxtErrorBoundary>
</template>
```

I want to retrieve data and display it on the interface, with the formatting preserved as it was when saved.
I have tried using the  tag, but it doesn't display correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK0p3.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and don't link like "enter image description here".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.